# Pass Values between components with an event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event, databinding

this app have 2 components, the first have 2 inputs and the other have a table to show the values of a list. I want to pass the values of the inputs throught an event to the second component an insert the objects there.
I can't push the code to the scratch org because of this error:

```
PROJECT PATH                                                 ERRORS                                         
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────
force-app\main\default\aura\crearCoche\crearCoche.cmp        c:crearCoche:9,75: Invalid attribute "event"   
force-app\main\default\aura\insertarCoche\insertarCoche.cmp  c:insertarCoche:5,71: Invalid attribute "event"
```

THANKS!!

:::::**HERE IS THE CODE**:::::

**MAIN APP**

```
<aura:application>
    <c:myComponent1/>
    <c:myComponent2/>
    <c:crearCoche/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="passValueEvent" type="c:passValueEvent"/>

</aura:application>
```

**FIRST COMPONENT**

```
<div class="c-container">
    <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="idCoche" label="Identificador Coche" />

    <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="nombre" label="Nombre Coche" />

    <lightning:button label="Introducir coche" onclick="{!c.crearCoche}"/>
    <aura:handler event="c:passValueEvent" action="{!c.handleEvent}"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER
**

```
 ({
       crearCoche : function(component, event) {
            var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:passValueEvent");
            var nombre = component.find('nombre').get("v.value");
            var id = component.find('idCoche').get("v.value");
            appevent.setParams({"cocheID": nombre},{"cocheNAME":id});
            console.log("firing event");
            appEvent.fire();


        }
    })
```

**SECOND COMPONENT**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="coches" type="List"></aura:attribute>

    <div class="c-container">
    <aura:handler event="c:passValueEvent" action="{!c.handleEvent}"/>
       <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
        </tr>
        <aura:iteration var="coche" items="{!c.coches}">
            <tr>
                <td>{coche.id}</td>
                <td>{coche.nombre}</td>
            </tr>

        </aura:iteration>
       </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
({
    createCar: function(nombre, color) {
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.nombre = nombre;
        obj.color = color;
        return obj;
      },


      insertCar: function(component, event) {
        var objs = component.get('v.coches');
        var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:passValueEvent");
        var nombre = appEvent.getParam("cocheNAME");
        var id = appEvent.getParam("cocheID")
        objs.push(this.createCar(nombre,id));
        component.set('v.objs', objs);
      },


})
```

**EVENT**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="cocheID" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cocheNAME" type="string"/>

</aura:event>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will fix your issue but there seems to be some issues with this chunk of code in your component 2 handler:

```
var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:passValueEvent");
var nombre = appEvent.getParam("cocheNAME");
var id = appEvent.getParam("cocheID")
objs.push(this.createCar(nombre,id));
```

In the handler you don't use `$A.get` to get the event, it is passed as a parameter so instead  of `var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:passValueEvent");` you should use `var appEvent = event;` (or use `event.getParam` on the following 2 lines)

The third line is missing a semi-colon.

I think `<aura:registerEvent name="passValueEvent" type="c:passValueEvent"/>` is supposed to be in the component that actually fires the event and not in the application. Move this into component 1. You also probably don't need a handler in component 1 unless there is code that was removed.

The best piece of advise I can give is to make sure your code more closely matches the [examples here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_example.htm).

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need to register in Application level. so replace with below code

`<aura:registerEvent name="passvalueappEvent" type="passValueEvent"/>`

in your first component below handler

```
<aura:handler event="c:passValueEvent" action="{!c.handleEvent}"/>`
```

remove at Application level